# How do I get HAML to render form labels with periods in them?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I'm making form labels like this

```
= f.label "16.36%"
```

But they are rendered like:

```
36%
```

Even if I escape it, it makes no difference. How do I get HAML to render form labels with periods in them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easy, don't use `f.label`. Use `label_tag` instead.

```
= label_tag '16.36%'
```

The reason why that happens is that usually `f.label` is used on actual field names. If you pass it a dotted string, it tries to interpret it as a complex field name (say, `'address.city'` or something). Since you don't need any of that, you can use a dumber version.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer and explanation!

Answer (score 0):

A way that worked for me was

```
<%= f.label :username, "Your unique username on example.com" %>
```

i.e. `<%= f.label <attribute>, "optional string to display on screen" %>`